# How can I enable and pass a data-test attribute to a component in Ember 2.16?

Tags: testing, ember.js

I have a basic component called like this:

```
{{my-component
    // more data here
    data-test-my-component="filter-questions" 
}}
```

and I am binding the attributes like this:

```
attributeBindings: [
    // more data here
    'data-test-my-component',
  ],
```

But I do not see this data attribute populated in my HTML.

Comment: Did you had a look at [ember-test-selectors](https://github.com/simplabs/ember-test-selectors)?

Comment: Yes @jelhan. It seems the compatibility starts at
Ember 3.8 or above (I am on 2.16).

Comment: You can use ember-test-selectors 3.0 and earlier.

Comment: Are you sure @Gaurav?
According to their doc you cannot: https://github.com/simplabs/ember-test-selectors#compatibility

Comment: The doc is for the current version of ember-test-selectors, 5.0. You can use 3.0 or earlier.